# Node.js - Mock result of a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I want to mock the result of a function within a node module so that i can run assertions.
Considering the following node module:

```
const doPostRequest = require('./doPostRequest.js').doPostRequest;
const normalizeSucessResult = require('./normalizer.js').normalizeSucessResult;
const normalizeErrorResult = require('./normalizer.js').normalizeErrorResult;

exports.doPost = (params, postData) => {
  return doPostRequest(params, postData).then((res) => {
    const normalizedSuccessResult = normalizeSucessResult(res);
    return normalizedSuccessResult;
  }).catch((err) => {
    const normalizedErrorResult = normalizeErrorResult(err);
    return normalizedErrorResult;
  })
}
```

The function `doPostRequest` returns a promise. How can i fake the return value of this promise so that i can assert if `normalizeSucessResult` has been called?
So for i have tried:

```
const normalizeSucessResult = require('./normalizer.js');
const doPostRequest = require('./doPostRequests.js');
const doPost = require('./doPost.js');

it('runs a happy flow scenario', async () => {
  let normalizeSucessResultStub = sinon.stub(normalizeSucessResult, 'normalizeSucessResult');
  let postData = { body: 'Lorum ipsum' };
  let params = { host: 'someUrl', port: 433, method: 'POST', path: '/' };

  sinon.stub(doPostRequest, 'doPostRequest').resolves("some response data"); //Fake response from doPostRequest

  return doPost.doPost(params, postData).then((res) => { //res should be equal to some response data
    expect(normalizeSucessResultStub).to.have.been.calledOnce;
    expect(normalizeSucessResultStub).to.have.been.with("some response data");
  });
});
```

The `doPostRequest` module looks like this:

```
const https = require('https')
 module.exports.doPostRequest = function (params, postData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(params, (res) => {
      let body = []
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk)
      })
      res.on('end', () => {
        try {
          body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString())
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e)
        }
        resolve(body)
      })
    })
    req.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err)
    })
    if (postData) {
      req.write(JSON.stringify(postData))
    }
    req.end()
  })
}
```

Comment: Where's doPostRequest defined? Please, post all relevant code.

Comment: The `doPostRequest` module is defined in a separate file. I have updated the code in order to show where it lives. If you have any ideas on how to solve this, please share. Im getting more confused by the minute...

Comment: I'm not up to detailed answer, but you need to mock the module where doPostRequest was exported from (with Proxyquire or something similar) and do this before you import the module where it's used the first time (i.e doPost) module. You cannot do this with Sinon. You can only mock existing methods with Sinon, while doPostRequest is used as a function, not a method. Btw, Jest handles module mocking natively, you could do this easier by switching to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i figured it out. The function `doPostRequest` was loaded using `require`, on the top of the file using `const doPostRequest = require('./doPostRequest.js').doPostRequest;`

In order to mock the data that comes back from a function that is loaded using `require` i had to use a node module called [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require). There are more modules that can take care of this ([proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) is a populair one) but i picked mock-require (i did not have a specific reason for choosing mock-require).

For anyone else that is stuck with a similar problem, try mock-require to mock the respose from files that are loaded using `require`.

Answer (score 21):

You can use [Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) to return a promise with any given value.

```
Promise.resolve(“hello world”);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried that in my code with `sinon.stub(doPostRequest, 'doPostRequest').resolves("some response data");`. Than when i call the method, `res` should be equal to `some response data`, but it is not. Can you show me how i can use it within my test so that `res` would be equal to `some response data`?

Answer (score 1):

For stub your func you need to do like this

`sinon.stub({doPostRequest}, 'doPostRequest').resolves("some response data")`